# Остановка события прокрутки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть `<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>`. Оба с прокруткой. У дива а прокрутка больше. Итак, уважаемые знатоки, как можно остановить прокрутку дива а при прокрутке дива б. `$('#b').on('wheel',function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
})`
не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/cqvnj1jj/):

```
$('#b').on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var evt = e.originalEvent,
    scrollTo = (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' ? evt.detail * 40 : evt.wheelDelta * -1);
    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Comment: Благодарю, на примере работает супер, но я подставил свой селектор и прокрут блока б остановился.